# How to convert JSON array to HTML table

Tags: php, html, json

I have the following function in a PHP script, which returns and API call:

```
if (in_array((int)$result['code'], array(200, 201))) {
    $presult=(json_decode($result['body'],true));
    print_r($presult);
 } else {
    print("error parsing result");
    var_dump($result);
 }
```

$presult displays raw data in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [contacts] => Array
        (
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Peter
                            [last_name] => Parker
```

I want to print this array in an HTML table with columns serial no., First name, Last

Comment: Hey deceze, thank you for editing my question. It's the first time I asked a question here and did not know how to format it. Much help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the array index is the serial number, so you can do this:

```
echo '<table>
<tr>
   <th>Serial Number</th>
   <th>First name</th>
   <th>Last name</th>
</tr>';

foreach($presult['contacts']['users'] as $number => $user){
   echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $number . '</td>
            <td>' . $user['first_name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $user['last_name'] . '</td>
         </tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

And don't forget to escape the HTML output if required.

Comment: Hi YMMD, yes this works fine. Thank you very much. But one more question, why it only runs for first 10 entries. There are total 298 entries. How to achieve that?? Also, like ['first_name'], there is something as ['photo_urls'], and then a sub array for links to different sizes of pictures. I am able to select one of the url's, but how to print the image in the column next to last_name, like a mini_thumb.

Comment: Hi all, I got all the entries and also the photo's in the table. I didn't set the limit for contacts in my API request and by default it returns 10 values. YMMD, thanks a lot.

Comment: 1.) You can output the images on the same way then seen above: Use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the whole array and `echo` every image where you want to have it. If you want to display it in a table cell you should open a `<td>` before that. -- 2.) The Code above does not limit the number of outputs in any way. It simply runs over all of them. Your array will probably not contain more then 10 results, please check that. :-)